# Reliably and definitively detect end of socket stream

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization

I'm fixing to use sockets to stream a sequence of bytes across a network. I'm using a binaryformatter to serialize the objects I wish to send, then just beam them between machines and deserialize them when the reach their destination. The question has been asked before "how do I detect the end of a bytestream", but my predicament is a little different. I want to be able to send multiple types of objects across this network. I would simply use a marker or agreed upon sequence of bytes to communicate the end of a message, but because I have no idea what the binaryformatter will produce, I don't know what sequence of characters I could use that would be unique. If i decided to use the sequence 255, 128, 0, 255 to denote the end of one object stream, how do I ensure that that sequence doesn't also occur within the binaryformatter output? What else can I do to signify the end of one object and the beginning of another?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need message framing if you can't control the content of your message.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I'm asking what I can use to frame said content that I can guarantee will be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normaly this is done with a lenght indication at the start of the message.

Lets say your compress your data (which can be a image, text etc.) into a byte array. You take the lenght of this byte array, lets say 500, and save this number at the start of your stream. The lenght in bytes of this lenght number must always be the same so lets say 32 bytes in the case of the number 500 it would look something like this)

```
00000000 00000000 00000001 11110100 and after this the 500 bytes of your actualy message comes
```

This way you always know how long your message is from reading the first 32 bytes and with that you know when the message ends.

Comment: That's actually really eloquent and obvious now that I see it. Thankyou so much for making it so plain. :)

Comment: yep people in the 60s where clever :)